# javascript/jQuery: firefox hangs on DOM loop insertion (show images one by one)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom, google-chrome

I have a function that requests some images from a server and returns these in a JSON format. I iterate these pictures (like 150) and insert each image in a div. I want the images to show up one by one, but the browser shows them all in one time. This makes Firefox hang.. In Safari/Chrome, the performance is OK, but they also show up pretty slow and not one at a time.

Any ideas? Here's my code:

loop part:

```
for (var i = 1; i < response.photos.length; i++) {
        var div = "a" + i;
        var subdiv = document.getElementById(div);
        var photo = response.photos[i-1]
        T.loadImage(photo, subdiv);
}
```

my loadImage function:

```
T.loadImage = function (photo, divv) {
    var subdiv = $(divv);
    var url = photo.url;
    var url_big = photo.url_big;
    if (url_big == undefined) {
        url_big = url;
    }

    subdiv.fadeOut();
    var identifier = subdiv.attr('class') + "x";

    var link = $("<a/>").attr("href", url_big).attr("id", identifier).appendTo(subdiv);
    var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", url).appendTo(link);
    img.imgCenter({parentSteps:1});

    subdiv.fadeIn();
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can could rework your load image function a bit to take advantage of the callback function in `fadeIn()`

Example:

```
var loadImage = function(photos, current) {

    if (current == count) {

        $("body").prepend((new Date() - startDate)/1000);
        return;
    }

    var div = $("<div id=a" + current + "></div>");
    $("body").append(div);
    var photo = photos[current];

    var url = photo.url;
    var url_big = photo.url_big;
    if (url_big === undefined) {
        url_big = url;
    }

    div.hide();
    var identifier = div.attr('class') + "x";

    var link = $("<a/>").attr("href", url_big).attr("id", identifier).appendTo(div);
    var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", url).appendTo(link);
    //img.imgCenter({parentSteps:1});
    div.fadeIn(5, function() {
        loadImage(photos, current + 1);
    });
};

loadImage(photos, current);
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EcsP4/2/).

Comment: This is what I need, but I should iterate them faster... I've tried changing div.fadeIn() to div.show() with a duration of 0 ms, but it is not faster. I want to fill my screen in let's say 2 seconds (for 150 pictures).. Is it possible with the above method? Thanks.

Comment: See update, added a durration for the example, shows in around 2 seconds for 150 images appended.

Comment: If there is an issue with loading still, if you could give me a sample image, or dimensions i might be able to tweak it a bit more to load like you want.

Comment: It worked! Great! Thanks. And pretty smooth on all browsers I tested yet.. (IE8, Firefox, Chrome, Safari).

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `.each` instead of the `for` loop.

e.g.

```
$.each(response.photos,function(index,photo){
    T.loadImage(photo, $("#a" + index));
});

T.loadImage = function (photo, divv) {
    var url = photo.url;
    var url_big = photo.url_big;
    if (url_big == undefined) {
        url_big = url;
    }

    divv.fadeOut();
    var identifier = divv.attr('class') + "x";

    var link = $("<a/>").attr("href", url_big).attr("id", identifier).appendTo(divv);
    var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", url).appendTo(link);
    img.imgCenter({parentSteps:1});

    divv.fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. Firefox still tries to load everything at once..

Comment: I've asked a friend who is working on linux/windows and for him it works in Firefox.. I'm working on a Mac though and I have this stupid loading mac lollypop icon :).. Any ideas why?